# Count based on multiple conditions using sqldf

Tags: sql, r, sqldf

Hi all I'm writing a sql query on R using sqldf and seem to hit a roadblock. I have a table with an Id column, two dates columns and a grouping by column.

```
AlertDate  AppointmentDate  ID  Branch
01/01/20   04/01/20         1   W1
01/01/20   09/01/20         1   W1
08/01/20   09/01/20         1   W2
01/01/20   23/01/20         1   W1
```

The query I'm writing is

```
sqldf('select Branch,count(ID) from df where AlertDate <= AppointmentDate 
and AppointmentDate <AlertDate+7 group by Branch')
```

From this query the result I'm getting is

```
Branch Count
W1      1
W2      1
```

Whichis correct based on the query. What I want to achieve is if my 2nd condition is false ie AppointmentDate is less than AlertDate+7. Instead of dropping the count it should be counted in the next group depending on date. Example if the alertdate is 01/01/20 and appointment date is 23/01/20 then it should be counted in W4. ceil((Appointmentdate-alertdate)/7) SO in the end I want the result as

```
Branch  Count
W1      1
W2      2
W4      1
```

The second row should be counted in W2 and 4th should be in W4 rather than being discarded. I was trying to achieve this in sql using sqldf in R. Any possible solution using R or Sql would work for me.

Output of dput(test)

```
structure(list(AlertDate = structure(c(18262, 18262, 18269, 18262), class = "Date"), AppointmentDate = structure(c(18265, 18270,18270, 18284), class = 
"Date"), ID = c(1, 1, 1, 1), Branch = c("W1","W1", "W2", "W1")), class = c("spec_tbl_df", "tbl_df", "tbl","data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -4L), problems = 
structure(list( row = 4L, col = "Branch", expected = "", actual = "embedded null", 
file = "'C:/Users/FRssarin/Desktop/test.txt'"), row.names = c(NA,-1L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")), spec = structure(list(  cols = list(AlertDate = 
structure(list(format = "%d/%m/%y"), class = c("collector_date", 
"collector")), AppointmentDate = structure(list(format = "%d/%m/%y"), class = c("collector_date",  "collector")), ID = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", "collector")), Branch = structure(list(), class = 
c("collector_character",  "collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess",  "collector")), skip = 1), class = "col_spec"))
```

[image]

Comment: Provide reproducible data, at the moment with your example and your query we are getting 2, 1, not 1,1. Post the output of `dput(head(df))`.

Comment: Hi, I've uploaded the image with the query result,  I'm getting 1,1 only.

Comment: Paste output of `dput(test)` as text please.

Comment: Why do you have a second condition if you do not care the condition output is True or False?

Comment: I care about the second condition, if the condition is true the count would be done in group1, if the condition is false it should do it in the next group like explained in the output.

Comment: You modified the question, can you dput your new df? i understood including the count in the next group if condition is not met, so i assume the fifth row is W4 rather than W3 hence you associated the 4th row that failed the condition to the next group in the next row (which is the 5th row)? You can do this with ifelse and lag.

Comment: From the above example, the first one goes in W1, the second should go to W2, the third should also go to W2 and the 4th row should go to W4. as the difference between appointment date and alertdate is greater than 3. (ciel (22/7)). Can you please send the code on how to do with if and lag? Updated the dput

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to do it using data.table

```
df <- structure(list(AlertDate = structure(c(18262, 18262, 18269, 18262), class = "Date"), AppointmentDate = structure(c(18265, 18270,18270, 18284), class = 
                                                                                                                     "Date"), ID = c(1, 1, 1, 1), Branch = c("W1","W1", "W2", "W1")), class = c("spec_tbl_df", "tbl_df", "tbl","data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -4L), problems = 
              structure(list( row = 4L, col = "Branch", expected = "", actual = "embedded null", 
                              file = "'C:/Users/FRssarin/Desktop/test.txt'"), row.names = c(NA,-1L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")), spec = structure(list(  cols = list(AlertDate = 
                                                                                                                                                                                      structure(list(format = "%d/%m/%y"), class = c("collector_date",
```

I am converting this to data.table and creating a new column for your logic.

```
library(data.table)
df <- data.table(df)
df <- df[AlertDate <= AppointmentDate] 
df[, new_branch:= ifelse(as.numeric(AppointmentDate-AlertDate)>=7
            ,paste0("W", as.character(ceiling(as.numeric(AppointmentDate-AlertDate)/7))),Branch)]
```

Here is the resulting table

```
    AlertDate AppointmentDate ID Branch new_branch
1: 2020-01-01      2020-01-04  1     W1         W1
2: 2020-01-01      2020-01-09  1     W1         W2
3: 2020-01-08      2020-01-09  1     W2         W2
4: 2020-01-01      2020-01-23  1     W1         W4
```

This is the goupby result..

```
df[, .(.N, alert=head(AlertDate,1),  appoint=head(AppointmentDate,1)), by = list(new_branch)]
   new_branch N      alert    appoint
1:         W1 1 2020-01-01 2020-01-04
2:         W2 2 2020-01-01 2020-01-09
3:         W4 1 2020-01-01 2020-01-23
```